# If a value isn't in table, display a standard message

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to be able to display a fallback statement if an entry in my database table doesn't exist.

On a user profile page I would like to display a phone number. If a user hasn't entered a phone number I would like to display a message to say 'no number has been provided.'

At present, I have been able to display nothing if the value doesn't exist, but this isn't ideal

How would I amend the current code I am using (below) to achieve this?

```
<?php if(!empty($profile['profile_phonenumber'])){ ?>
<?php echo $profile['profile_phonenumber'] ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: There isn't any more straightforward than this... Your code is already what you're looking for. Unless you're using a PHP framework, it may offer a shortcut for this.

Comment: However he still needs to handle the else clause where there is no value returned ;-) that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it several way:
Through php:

```
echo  (!empty($profile['profile_phonenumber'])) ?
     $profile['profile_phonenumber'] : 'No phone provided';
```

if you are using mysql: then in select query:

```
select if(length(profile_phonenumber)>0,profile_phonenumber,'profile_phonenumber') as profile_phonenumber,<other column name>  from <tablename> where <your_condition>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code with `else` clause:

```
if (!empty($profile['profile_phonenumber'])) {
    echo $profile['profile_phonenumber'];
} else {
    echo 'No phone provided';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Ternary operator. Try this code:

```
<?php 
  echo (!empty($profile['profile_phonenumber'])) ? $profile['profile_phonenumber'] : "no number has been provided"; 
?>
```